# Madness from Depression

Tags: abnormal-psychology, psychiatry

I have been wondering about this for a while... I've known people that struggle against depression and are medicated with SSRIs but there was a case that I found quite intriguing. There was a nineteen-year-old boy that didn't show any revealing symptoms of depression, other than unexplained stomach pains and nausea and the meds did fix that up for him. The thing is, he started to become quite detached, almost obsessed with studying others and started to present symptoms of detachment from other humans and some other weird behaviours. 
Could this be related to SSRIs less studied side-effects?

Comment: If the boy have no signs of depression, why would you say that his behaviours are related to SSRIs side effects? In my own understanding, why would someone prescribed him with SSRI, when in the first place,  he had no signs and symptoms of depression?

Comment: Would you provide us the case you're talking about? links or sites?

Comment: Because the nausea he was feeling everyday was diagnosed as  psychossomatic. Although he didn't express a anxious or depressive mood, his body would suffer from it.

Comment: That's why 1-2 weeks after starting SSRIs the nausea disappeared. It's not a medical study case, it's a close person I know.

Comment: i would advise you to seek help of a psychiatrist. They would be glad to answer your query. But a word of advise, keep an eye on him "from time to time". Detaching himself from the environment may increase the likelihood of him to commit suicide. I will give my explanation later.